# How can I exclude a user with a specific id in MySQL

Tags: mysql

How can I exclude a user with a user_id of 1 for example from the following query below?

Here is My MySQL code.

```
"SELECT users.*, COUNT(*) as coun, users_comments.user_id 
FROM users_comments
INNER JOIN users ON users_comments.user_id = users.user_id
GROUP BY users_comments.user_id 
ORDER BY coun DESC
LIMIT 5"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT users.*, COUNT(*) as coun, users_comments.user_id 
FROM users_comments
INNER JOIN users ON users_comments.user_id = users.user_id
WHERE users.user_id != 1 <---------------
GROUP BY users_comments.user_id 
ORDER BY coun DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT users.*, COUNT(*) as coun, users_comments.user_id 
FROM users_comments
JOIN users ON users_comments.user_id = users.user_id
WHERE users.user_id not in(1,3) 
GROUP BY users_comments.user_id 
ORDER BY coun DESC
LIMIT 0,5
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.